# How do I access the underlying Jackson ObjectMapper in REST Assured?

Tags: java, jackson, rest-assured

I need to configure the underlying Jackson ObjectMapper in REST Assured. I am writing REST API tests using REST Assured and I need to define some filters to register with the ObjectMapper that is used to serialize my objects to JSON:

```
    String newTestSuite = "{\"name\":\"Added through Rest API\",\"description\":\"Test Description\",\"steps\":[]}";

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("createNewTestSuite", new NewTestSuiteFilter());
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.setFilters(filters);

    try {
        TestSuite ts = om.readValue(newCaspianTest, TestSuite.class);

        RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setBaseUri("https://somesite.com")
            .setBody(ts)
            .setUrlEncodingEnabled(false)
            .build();

        ResponseSpecification responseSpec = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
            .expectStatusCode(200)
            .expectStatusLine(Matchers.containsString("200 OK"))
            .build();

        RestAssured.given()
            .auth().basic("testUser","testPassword")
            .spec(requestSpec)
            .log().all()
            .post("/restendpoint")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .spec(responseSpec);

    } catch(JsonParseException jpe) {

    } catch(JsonMappingException jme) {

    } catch(IOException ioe) {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try this:

```java
RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(
new Jackson2ObjectMapperFactory() {
        @Override
        public ObjectMapper create(Class aClass, String s) {
            FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(...);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setFilters(filter);
            return objectMapper;
        }
    }
));
```

Comment: I am trying this solution out right now, but I have one question -- It's not possible to use a type parameter with the Class argument here is it? I have to use the raw class type?

Comment: This worked great! I did have an issue with Eclipse complaining that I had not overridden a superclass method, but I found that my java compiler compliance level was set to 1.5 and support for the Override annotation on implemented methods from an interface was not added until java 1.6. Once I changed my Eclipse preferences, the error went away.

Comment: I've tried this but my filter is never called.  I've gone through the Jackson code and, while I see my filter being passed around as part of the FilterProvider in the configuration, the filter itself is never invoked.  Did you have any similar difficulties?

Comment: Ok, I've found that I have to override the annotation introspector since my classes do not refer to this filter in any way.  However, this raises another question for me that I've posted here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833259/jackson-how-to-add-property-filter-without-overriding-annotation-filters]

Answer (score 12):

This will give you an object mapper that does not explode when the back end developer decides to add a new field.

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(
    new Jackson2ObjectMapperFactory() {
      @Override
      public ObjectMapper create(Type cls, String charset) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return om;
      }          

    }
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the context for which Rest Assured is used, often times you'll want to modify or provide the `ObjectMapper` used for *some* request, but not all of them.

You can achieve this by using the methods:

- [`.body(Object object, ObjectMapper mapper)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#body-java.lang.Object-io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper-) or [`.content(Object object, ObjectMapper mapper)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#content-java.lang.Object-io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper-)**(deprecated** in favor of `.body()`), to serialize your request body/payload.
- [`.as(Type cls, ObjectMapper mapper)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/response/ResponseBodyExtractionOptions.html#as-java.lang.reflect.Type-io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper-) or [`.as(Class<T> cls, ObjectMapper mapper)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/response/ResponseBodyExtractionOptions.html#as-java.lang.Class-io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper-), to deserialize your request's response body.

A classic use case, as [@jason-henriksen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10946259/jason-henriksen) mentioned is to

- Allow unknown properties to be ignored
- Ignore properties defined in your `ReturnedType` class that are not marked with [`@JsonIgnore`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) without throwing an Exception during the deserialization (useful when you have no control/ can't modify that `ReturnedType` class <sup>1</sup>)

This can be done with:

```
RequestSpecification request = ...;
io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new Jackson2Mapper(((type, charset) -> {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
    om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return om;
}));
ReturnType response = request.get().as(ReturnType.class, objectMapper);
```

<sup>1</sup>  You can also achieve this by configuring your ObjectMapper with [Jackson MixIns](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me! In my case, the deserialization was failing at .as(...) and passing in a custom objectMapper was the easiest solution that didn't require changing it everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

@sanj's answer was very helpful. I had to modify it slightly because I'm using RestAssuredMockMvc.

This is how I configure RestAssuredMockMvc to use *snake_case* instead of *CamelCase*:

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.config = RestAssuredMockMvcConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(
            (type, s) -> {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
                return objectMapper;
            }
    ));
```