# Disable sending null fields via Rest Assured in runtime

Tags: java, json, rest, http, rest-assured

Lets assume that I got following model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class MyModel {
    private Object field; //required field
    private Object anotherField; //optional field
}
```

Now I would like to verify if my REST endpoint is working properly (is expecting only required field), so I would like to perform following 2 requests and check if they result in 200:

```
{
    "field": "someValue",
    "anotherField": null
}
```

and:

```
{
    "field": "someValue"
}
```

With the first one, the code is simple:

```
MyModel payload = MyModel.builder().field("someValue").build();
when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).put("http://my-service.com/myendpoint/").then().statusCode(200);
```

But the second one is starting to be a little bit crippy. If I won't provide value for `anotherField`, by default it will be null, and thats what will be sent via REST (first TCs). But at this moment **I don't want to send this field**. In other words:

#### I want RestAssured to don't send `nulls`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. After a little bit of investigation I see two ways of solving this problem:

1. Customize mapper used by restassured: [How do I access the underlying Jackson ObjectMapper in REST Assured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070085/how-do-i-access-the-underlying-jackson-objectmapper-in-rest-assured)
2. Serialize my object to String before sending.

I choosed second option:

```
String payload;
//send model WITHOUT nulls
payload = new Gson().toJson(MyModel.builder().field("someValue").build());
when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).put("http://my-service.com/myendpoint/").then().statusCode(200);

//send model WITH nulls
payload = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().toJson(MyModel.builder().field("someValue").build());
when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).put("http://my-service.com/myendpoint/").then().statusCode(200);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Jackson library:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

> using this annotation one can specify simple exclusion rules to reduce
>   amount of properties to write out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here : **private Object anotherField; //optional field**.

You have not defined this property as **nullable type**. According to your code it is required field not nullable type. You have to add **data annotations** to define it as nullable type.